# Missing one custom field when getting SharePoint List Items in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-list

In MS Graph Explorer, when making an API call

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?expand=fields(select=id,ProjectMembers)
```

the `ProjectMembers` custom field is missing across all items returned, even though the field exists.

When I make a call for one specific item at a time, like

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{id}?expand=fields(select=id,ProjectMembers)
```

I successfully get the `ProjectMembers` custom field - now, I could go this way as a workaround, but then I have to make a separate call for every item I have in my list (thousands of items resulting in thousands of API calls), rather than making one call (the first call above) and using pagination.

I have successfully fetched a couple of other relevant custom fields through both first and second API call, but fetching the `ProjectMembers` field through the first "bulk" call just doesn't work

Has anyone faced a similar issue before and/or has a solution/explanation to this?

Comment: What type of column ProjectMembers is? like text, lookup, multivalue, etc?

Comment: @user2250152 I'm assuming its a lookup, here is a sample structure I get when querying for a specific item:  
`"ProjectMemebers": [{"LookupId": 100,"LookupValue": "John Doe","Email": "johndoe@company.com"},{"LookupId": 101,"LookupValue": "Jane Doe","Email": "janedoe@company.com"}]`

Comment: I guess that ProjectMemebers is only typo in the comment

Comment: yeah my bad, I made a typo in my comment, it is "ProjectMembers", not "ProjectMemebers"